# Can I pass setState from parent to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React's documentation recommends passing functions as properties to child components in order to alter state variables of the parent. I'm finding this design to be a little cluttered on parents that hold lots of differing child components.

I started doing this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const that = this;
  this.state = {
    parentData : '',
    setState : function(obj) { // <--
      that.setState(obj)
    }
  };
}
render() {
  <Child prop={this.state} />
}
```

Then in the child when I need to alter parent state:

```
childFunction() {
  props.setState({ parentData: 'new data'})
}
```

Are there any downsides to this implementation?

Comment: You should keep state local to the respective component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One large downside is that it's much harder to track down where the state is being updated once your application starts to grow.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you shouldn't do is actually store this function on the `state` of the parent component but passing a function from the parent to the child that might eventually update parent's state is a valid and [frequently](https://www.google.com/search?q=react%20passing%20function%20as%20props&oq=react%20passing%20function%20as%20props&aqs=chrome..69i57.2885j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) used pattern in React.

```js
const Child = ({ updateParent }) => (
  <div id="child">
    <button onClick={() => updateParent(Math.random())}>
      Update Parent
    </button>
  </div>
);

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data : ''
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="parent">
        <h3>Data: {this.state.data}</h3>
        <Child updateParent={(data) => this.setState({ data })} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.querySelector('#example')
)
```

```css
#parent {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: olivedrab;
  color: #fff;
}

#parent:before {
  content: 'Parent';
}

#child {
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#child:before {
  content: 'Child';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: I'm quite familiar with this pattern, and I do utilize it across parts of my app. Does passing setState negatively impact performance / concurrency etc.?

Comment: If you mean passing `setState` directly, that won't really work because passing a function on its own would make `this` within it not point to the react component anymore and point to something else (depending on how the function is called within the child). That's one of the reasons you pass a wrapper function instead.

Comment: But it does work; I set `that = this` in the constructor of the parent (see code in question), then using `that.setState(...)` so `this` is bound to the proper scope.

Comment: In that case, there's no difference from my example, both use a wrapper function. The only difference is that you have your wrapper function on the state object itself, which doesn't make sense because a function isn't a state that gets modified over time